# Adding grid lines to a ggplot independent of axis breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridlines

I have data on abundance over a sequence of nucleotides (ordered character sequence of A, T, C, and G) by two different categories. I want to use ggplot to show the coverage as a line plot over the sequence. I've gotten reasonably far and have just a few more hurdles to jump. Sample data:

```
> dput(so.sample)
structure(list(`1_mes_wt` = c(0, 0, 4.25897346349789, 10.0666645500859, 
10.0666645500859, 48.3974257215669, 78.2102399660521, 250.698665237717, 
250.698665237717, 268.702507606139, 271.79994285232, 301.225577691032, 
301.225577691032, 301.225577691032, 301.225577691032, 311.292242241118, 
311.292242241118, 311.292242241118, 311.292242241118, 311.292242241118, 
311.292242241118, 311.292242241118, 311.292242241118, 311.292242241118, 
311.292242241118, 311.292242241118, 311.292242241118, 321.746086196977, 
321.746086196977, 321.746086196977, 319.616599465228, 308.969165806483, 
285.931991163017, 204.817905653671, 195.332010212244, 170.165348837029, 
170.165348837029, 170.165348837029, 170.165348837029, 37.3628126570497, 
40.8474273090025, 22.456405534807, 22.456405534807, 17.8102526655366, 
17.8102526655366, 17.8102526655366, 17.8102526655366, 17.8102526655366, 
17.8102526655366, 17.8102526655366, 17.8102526655366, 15.6807659337877, 
15.6807659337877, 15.6807659337877, 15.6807659337877, 15.6807659337877, 
15.6807659337877, 15.6807659337877, 15.6807659337877, 15.6807659337877, 
15.6807659337877, 15.6807659337877, 15.6807659337877, 15.6807659337877, 
15.6807659337877, 15.6807659337877, 5.22692197792922, 5.22692197792922, 
5.22692197792922, 5.22692197792922, 5.22692197792922, 5.22692197792922, 
5.22692197792922, 5.22692197792922, 5.22692197792922, 5.22692197792922, 
5.22692197792922, 1.74230732597641, 1.93589702886268, 1.93589702886268, 
4.25897346349789, 2.71025584040775, 2.71025584040775, 68.5307548217387, 
89.6320324363419, 90.0192118421144, 93.310236791181, 93.1166470882947, 
93.5038264940673, 93.8910058998398, 93.8910058998398, 93.8910058998398, 
93.8910058998398, 93.8910058998398, 93.8910058998398, 93.8910058998398, 
93.8910058998398, 93.8910058998398, 93.8910058998398, 93.8910058998398, 
93.8910058998398, 93.8910058998398, 93.8910058998398, 93.8910058998398, 
93.8910058998398, 93.6974161969535, 93.6974161969535, 93.6974161969535, 
93.6974161969535, 93.6974161969535, 93.6974161969535, 93.6974161969535, 
93.6974161969535, 93.6974161969535, 89.2448530305694, 77.2422914516208, 
1.16153821731761, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2_mes_wt` = c(0, 0, 13.3249362857652, 
41.0267775114349, 41.3774337294814, 100.988990797378, 100.988990797378, 
341.188500159198, 343.643093685523, 359.422623497613, 381.163309016493, 
450.242583971645, 450.242583971645, 450.242583971645, 450.242583971645, 
450.242583971645, 450.242583971645, 450.242583971645, 450.242583971645, 
450.242583971645, 450.242583971645, 450.242583971645, 450.242583971645, 
450.242583971645, 450.242583971645, 450.242583971645, 450.242583971645, 
450.242583971645, 450.242583971645, 450.242583971645, 450.242583971645, 
426.047304926439, 366.085091640496, 308.928128098924, 201.977981594756, 
201.977981594756, 205.133887557174, 205.133887557174, 205.133887557174, 
85.5601172033343, 98.8850534890995, 17.1821546842762, 17.1821546842762, 
17.1821546842762, 17.1821546842762, 17.1821546842762, 17.1821546842762, 
16.8314984662297, 16.8314984662297, 16.8314984662297, 16.8314984662297, 
50.8451516167356, 52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 
52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 
52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 
52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 
52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 
52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 
52.5984327069678, 52.5984327069678, 39.2734964212026, 37.5202153309704, 
42.0787461655743, 54.7023700152465, 54.7023700152465, 54.7023700152465, 
113.261958429004, 114.313927083143, 114.313927083143, 116.067208173376, 
82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 
82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 
82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 
82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 
82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 
82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 
82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 82.0535550228698, 74.3391182258479, 
63.4687754664078, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), nucl = 47738064:47738184, base = c("T", 
"C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "G", "A", "C", "T", "A", "G", 
"T", "C", "A", "A", "G", "T", "G", "C", "A", "G", "T", "A", "G", 
"T", "G", "A", "G", "A", "A", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "A", 
"A", "A", "G", "T", "G", "T", "A", "G", "A", "A", "C", "A", "G", 
"G", "A", "G", "T", "T", "C", "A", "A", "T", "C", "T", "G", "T", 
"A", "A", "C", "T", "G", "A", "C", "T", "G", "T", "G", "A", "A", 
"C", "A", "A", "T", "C", "A", "A", "T", "T", "G", "A", "G", "A", 
"T", "A", "A", "C", "T", "C", "A", "C", "T", "A", "C", "C", "T", 
"T", "C", "G", "G", "A", "C", "C", "A", "G", "C", "C", "A", "A", 
"T", "G", "C")), .Names = c("1_mes_wt", "2_mes_wt", "nucl", "base"
), row.names = c(NA, -121L), class = "data.frame")
```

To show both the sequence (base) and the sequence positions (nucl) I plot the position as factors and then use a text geom to label the axis with the sequence. It works reasonably well:

```
pdf("so_sample.pdf",width=15,height=7)
ggplot(melt(so.sample,id.vars=c("nucl","base")), aes(factor(nucl), 
       value, group=variable, colour=variable)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_text(y=-5,size=3,aes(label=base))
dev.off()
```

[image]

However, plotting these large numbers as factors causes major overlapping and I don't need to see each position label anyway. So I remove some of the breaks.

```
pdf("so_sample2.pdf",width=15,height=7)
ggplot(melt(so.sample,id.vars=c("nucl","base")), aes(factor(nucl), 
       value, group=variable, colour=variable)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_text(y=-5,size=3,aes(label=base)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(min(so.sample$nucl),
                   max(so.sample$nucl),10))
dev.off()
```

[image]

I am almost there, but in removing the breaks I have also removed the minor grid lines that are particularly useful alongside the character sequence. Is there any way of adding minor grid lines independent of the breaks specified in `scale_x_discrete`?

And one side question: The sequence labeling works because it is plotting the same characters in the exact same position for each grouping, and the final colour of these labels is determined by the order of plotting the groups. I would prefer the sequence to be a neutral colour, but I have no idea if it is even possible to give `geom_text` these values independent of the groupings.

Comment: why are you converting `nucl` to a `factor`? Leave it as is, and use `scale_x_continuous` with `minor_breaks`.

Comment: @mplourde Thanks, I was being convoluted :P. Write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving `nucl` as is without wrapping it in call to `factor` allows you to use `scale_x_continuous`, which unlike `scale_x_discrete`, has a `minor_breaks` argument.